# Why does (condp contains? (:symbols xx) :a (prn "yes")) give contains? not supported on type: clojure.lang.Keyword error?

Tags: clojure

I want to use condp for a problem.

This is what I am trying to checking using condp.

```
(def xx {:symbols {:a 1}})

(contains? (:symbols xx) :a)

true
```

But I get this error

```
(condp contains? (:symbols xx) :a (prn "yes"))

IllegalArgumentException contains? not supported on type:     
clojure.lang.Keyword  clojure.lang.RT.contains
```

Comment: Please update your question with the value of `xx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the order of arguments being passed to `contains?` by [`condp`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/condp) — it's passing the keyword as the first argument. If you create an anonymous function that swaps the argument order, it'll do what you want:

```
user=> (def xx {:symbols #{:a :b}})
user=> (condp #(contains? %2 %1) (:symbols xx) :a (prn "yes"))
"yes"
nil
```

This is the relevant line from the `condp` doc string explaining that argument-order behavior:

> For each clause, (pred test-expr expr) is evaluated.

Comment: Thank you for answering @TaylorWood !!